# Error: Compile Error,ByRef argument type mismatch

Tags: vba, ms-access, compiler-errors

I have an error that says "Compile Error,ByRef  argument type mismatch". Can anyone let me know why this error occurs or how to fix this?

Comment: I strongly suggest to put [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) at the top of each module.  
It enforces variable declaration and reports undeclared or misspelled variables/constants at compile time. 
To have this automatically in new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor.

Comment: now it says "Variable not defined" by pointing at row "argcount=0"

Comment: Yes, that's the point. Declare all variables with well-defined variable types to prevent these problems. *Being able to generate compile time errors rather than runtime errors is a fundamental part of writing better code.*

Comment: how to declare sql statment in my case? because now it's giving error varlable not declare in sql statment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of your sub is:

```
Private Sub AddtoWhere(FieldValue As Variant, FieldName As String, mycriteria As String, argcount As Integer)
```

You are calling it as (for example):

```
AddtoWhere cboProduct1, "Product", mycriteria, argcount
```

Because you have only declared one variable (`Search` as a `String`) all other variables are declared as `Variant` by default.

This means you are trying to pass:

- `cboProduct1` (a `Variant`) to `FieldValue` (a `Variant`) - because a `Variant` can be a `Variant/Object`, it is possible that `cboProduct1` is an object of some sort (ComboBox?) and this will be handled correctly
- `"Product"` (a `String`) to `FieldName` (a `String`)
- `mycriteria` (a `Variant`) to `mycriteria` (a `String`)
- `argcount` (a `Variant`) to `argcount` (a `Integer`)

Because the variables being passed to `myCriteria` and `argCount` do not have the same data type, you get an error.

The best way around the problem (and the best thing to do even if you didn't have a problem) would be to declare all your variables.

So add the following statements (at least) to your `cmdsearch1_Click` subroutine:

```
Dim mycriteria As String
Dim argcount As Integer
```

Comment: i declare in cmdsearch1 ,now it's giving error variable not define in sql statment. explaning: cboProduct is Product combo box that have numbers .

Comment: @ABC I assume that it is the `Me!sfrmtblCapCrstab.Form.RecordSource = mysource` line which is giving the error - is that so?  (It helps us help you if you tell us that sort of thing, rather than making us guess!)  If so, what is the value of `mySource` - it sounds like it isn't a valid SQL statement.

Comment: @ABC Also, are all the field names you use in the SQL statement the names of fields that exist in your `[tblCapCrstab]` table?  (And is `Source` a reserved word?  [I don't use Access and/or SQL enough to know]  If it is, make sure you wrap the field name with brackets, i.e. use `[Source]` as the field name.  It's usually a good idea to do that anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

When you pass an argument by **reference** it means you are **passing** a function or sub the **same values** you have previously. It expects **to receive the same**. A quick fix for you problem could be to change the function/sub definition to expect variant or to make sure you are passing correct type.

Hope this helped, leave some code next time so we can help more.

Comment: attach is the code , sorry i didn't understand what you said, can you explain a bit more.